# autograd.grad error: One of the differentiated Tensors appears to not have been used in the graph

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am using the following code. I have to use `autograd.grad` twice. The first time it runs.

The second time, it gives the error

```
One of the differentiated Tensors appears to not have been used in the graph
```

The code is shown below

```
import torch

x=torch.randn(10,3).float()
x.requires_grad=True

y=torch.sum(x,1)
y2=torch.flatten(y)

L1=torch.nn.Linear(10, 50) 
L2=torch.nn.Linear(50, 50)
L3=torch.nn.Linear(50, 10)

u=L1(y2)
u=L2(u)
u=L3(u)

u=u.reshape(u.shape,1)

# the first autograd.grad works ok as expected
u_x=torch.autograd.grad(u,x,torch.ones(u.shape),retain_graph=True,create_graph=True)[0]

# error in the last line
u_xx=torch.autograd.grad(u_x,x,torch.ones(u_x.shape),create_graph=True)[0]
```

I am not sure why the second time `autograd.grad` is not working.

Comment: Have you solved this issue since? I'm facing a similar problem.